# Specify SSL CACERT in Django to run through Cuttle Proxy

Tags: python, django, ssl, proxy, urllib2

I'm trying to use [Cuttle Proxy](https://github.com/mrkschan/cuttle) with Django to rate-limit the calls our app does to the Shopify API.

I've deployed Cuttle to a box and it's running. Problem is, I'm not sure how I would specify a CACERT to keep SSL happy on Django's end.

Cuttle suggests you create a certificate as such

`openssl req -x509 -nodes -sha1 -newkey rsa:2048 -out cacert.pem -outform PEM -days 1825`

and then use it with your http client like so:

`https_proxy='127.0.0.1:3128' curl --cacert cacert.pem https://www.example.com/api/`

How would I do the above when running Django? If I specify the HTTPS_PROXY,

`HTTPS_PROXY='cuttle.mydomain.com:3128' python manage.py runserver`

I get the following error:

`<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)>`

The shopify Python API uses [pyactiveresource](https://github.com/Shopify/pyactiveresource/). If pyactiveresource were using the [requests](http://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library it could be specified fairly easily, but it seems to be using [urllib.Requests](https://github.com/Shopify/pyactiveresource/blob/master/pyactiveresource/connection.py#L108). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but we ended up going with the much simpler route of monkey patching [`ShopifyConnection`](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api/blob/master/shopify/base.py#L13) within the `shopify` module to insert the rate limiting logic. Here's the basic scaffolding:

```
from pyactiveresource.activeresource import formats
from pyactiveresource.connection     import Connection, ConnectionError

class RateLimitedShopifyConnection(Connection, object):
    response = None

    def __init__(self, site, user=None, password=None, timeout=None,
                 format=formats.JSONFormat):
        super(ShopifyConnection, self).__init__(
            site, user, password,timeout, format
        )

    def rate_limit(self):
        # Blocking logic here

    def _open(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.response = None
        try:
            self.rate_limit()
            self.response = super(RateLimitedShopifyConnection, self)._open(
                *args, **kwargs
            )
        except pyactiveresource.connection.ConnectionError as err:
            self.response = err.response
            raise
        return self.response

# Monkey patch
import shopify
shopify.base.ShopifyConnection = RateLimitedShopifyConnection
```

You can use `self.site` to get the user's domain as a unique identifier. With our setup, we use in-memory database Redis to implement a cross-request Token Bucket algorithm which complements Shopify's Leaky Bucket algorithm perfectly. You can also simply use `sleep(0.5)` and that should work just fine too.

You'll want to put this in a file (we call it `shopify_limiter.py`), have it in your main app's directory and import it in that app's `__init__.py` to make sure it gets loaded.